# Stack one using numpy.hstack

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my code

```py
    m, n = x.shape # m = 100, n = 20
    x = np.hstack((x, [1]*m))
```

I try to make something like this

```
datasetX = [[2,2],  [1,2],  [3,4],  [1,1],  [3,3],  [7,2],  [5,2],  [6,1],  [8,0],  [7,3]]
```

to this

```
x = [[2,2,1],  [1,2,1],  [3,4,1],  [1,1,1],  [3,3,1],  [7,2,1],  [5,2,1],  [6,1,1],  [8,0,1],  [7,3,1]]
```

It gives

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s)
```

May I ask why and how to solve it?

Comment: `np.hstack((x, np.ones((len(x),1), dtype=x.dtype)))`. You need a 'column' array with shape(m,1).

Comment: it works. Thank you.

Comment: Or `np.column_stack((x, [1]*m))`, a little bit nicer.

Comment: `np.array([1]*m)` has shape (m,).

Comment: `np.insert(x, 2, 1, 1)` works too.